# error in write code in php

Tags: php, if-statement

i want a system like this :

```
function check()
{
      $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$this->ClientID' 
            AND username='$this->ClientUSERNAME'") or die(mysql_error());
      $showmysql = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery );
      $statusOK = $showmysql['status'];
      if ($statusOK == "Active" || "1");{
         return true;
      }
      else if ($statusOK == "Pending");{
           $this->Redirect("pending.php");
      }
      else if ($statusOK == "Susspended");{
           $this->Redirect("sus.pjp");
      }
}
```

But When i put this codes in adobe dreamweaver i see the **errors** in `(})`... What is my problem?Please write the true code

Comment: What errors do you get? Is PHP installed on your system where you run Dreamweaver?

Comment: why have you got <br> tags in php code? this is html code and should be outside php tags

Comment: Oh..I thought he used them for new lines, if I'm wrong please rollback my edit

Comment: http://www.8pic.ir/images/30499752745488909759.png

Comment: http://www.8pic.ir/images/30499752745488909759.png  ... my problem is in } ... not br ... i just put br for show the code true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove semicolon `;` from `if-else`

```
if ($statusOK == "Active" || "1");{
                                 ^
else if ($statusOK == "Pending");{
                                ^  


if ($statusOK == "Active" || "1") {

else if ($statusOK == "Pending") {
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolons into your conditions like `if, else if`

```
<?php
function check()
{
    $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$this->ClientID'
      AND username='$this->ClientUSERNAME'") or die(mysql_error());
    $showmysql = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery );
    $statusOK = $showmysql['status'];
    if ($statusOK == "Active" || "1")
    {
       return true;
    }
    else if  ($statusOK == "Pending")
    {
       $this->Redirect("pending.php");
    }
    else if ($statusOK == "Susspended"){
       $this->Redirect("sus.pjp");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check()
{
    $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$this->ClientID' AND username='$this->ClientUSERNAME'") or die(mysql_error());
    $showmysql = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery );
    $statusOK = $showmysql['status'];
    if ($statusOK == "Active" || "1") {
        return true;
    }
    else if ($statusOK == "Pending") {
        $this->Redirect("pending.php");
    }
    else if ($statusOK == "Susspended") {
        $this->Redirect("sus.pjp");
    }
}
```

Remove semicolon(;) after if else if then it will work. Try it...

Answer (score 0):

Remove Semicolon after if else condition and try it below code

```
function check()
{
      $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$this->ClientID' 
            AND username='$this->ClientUSERNAME'") or die(mysql_error());
      $showmysql = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery );
      $statusOK = $showmysql['status'];
      if ($statusOK == "Active" || "1"){
         return true;
      }
      else if ($statusOK == "Pending"){
           $this->Redirect("pending.php");
      }
      else if ($statusOK == "Susspended"){
           $this->Redirect("sus.pjp");
      }
}
```

Comment: Again i Have problem !!!!! When i put in status row Pending And run this function the page not redirect to pending.php ... Susspended is to !!! what is the problem?

Comment: Redirect is not php function so using header function of php just see example  header('Location: http://www.example.com/index.php');